# Intellij - Debugger Breakpoints not working anymore

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

I was working/debugging normally on my `Java-Maven` project with `IntelliJ 2018.2.1`, I then click on Intellij to Stop the app to make some modifications to the code and when I start the application again in debug mode, it (the debugger) simply stopped working.

Now, the application takes about +10+20 seconds to start and when the breakpoints are hit, it simply hangs and do nothing else.

I have tried many of the suggestions posted on Internet, but none of those seems to work. I also tried to `Invalidate/Restart the IDE`, but nothing.

Now, the breakpoints aren't even marked as valid any more, it only shows the red circle without the tick verification check. And it also extended to all projects, so now none of the projects the debugger works and the same symptoms are in all projects.

If anyone have any suggestion on this, would really appreciate it.

Comment: close IDEA. build maven project using (mvn clean install). then open IDEA and the project and re-import it. then in run/debug configuration set the right module to  pick the class path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue. It ended up being that I am using another application (`NetLimiter`) to limit the traffic in the network and I limited few days ago `IntelliJ` to consume only 5 kbps at any time and this was the problem. I simply removed the limitation and the debugger starting working again normally at its usual speed.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically caused because there is a process running that it is connected to but you have no way to find it.

The only way to resolve it is to reboot your machine.

Comment: Nope, I already tried restarting the machine. No tick is shown for any of the breakpoints and none of the breakpoints work.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, the application takes about +10+20 seconds to start and when the
>   breakpoints are hit, it simply hangs and do nothing else.

By this syptom I can suggest that you have accidentally added some field or method breakpoint. Please check that there are no field or method breakpoints present in Breakpoints window (`Ctrl + Shift + F8`). If they exist - remove them.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Under Intellij Idea

1. click on Edit Configuration
2. Go to Run and add below command
3. spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.fork=false

[image]