# Breakpoints doesn't working on Maven IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I have a problem with my project. I use IntelliJ Ultimate.
I have added the maven framework and configuration like this:

[image]

The breakpoints are marked in red correctly, but the flow does not stop when passing through there. The application compiles and runs correctly.

The strange thing is that if I use the Spring Boot configuration, the breakpoints do work:
[image]

The problem is that for each change I make I have to do a clean, build and compile and
it is very tedious.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>car-pooling-challenge-leandro_92</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

PD: These answers did not solve my problem:
[Debugger does not stop on breakpoints in simple Maven project in IntelliJ 2017.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895984/debugger-does-not-stop-on-breakpoints-in-simple-maven-project-in-intellij-2017-1)
[IntelliJ debugger not hitting breakpoints in a Maven Java Google App Engine project (Eclipse works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351090/intellij-debugger-not-hitting-breakpoints-in-a-maven-java-google-app-engine-proj)
[Intellij - Debugger Breakpoints not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496517/intellij-debugger-breakpoints-not-working-anymore)

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you set your breakpoint? Which version of IDEA ULtimate do you use?

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66599810/8203759